# Find the speed of a jet given the time of travel back and forth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, factoring, quadratics

The problem:

> A jet flew from Tokyo to Bangkok, a distance of 4800km. On the return
>   trip, the speed was decreased by 200 km/h. If the difference in the
>   times of the flights was 2 hours, what was the jet's speed from
>   Bangkok to Tokyo?

From the problem, we can see that the variables are:

**Distance:**

T to B = 4800km

B to T = 4800km

**Speed:**

T to B = $x$km/h

B to T = $x-200$km/h

**Time:**

T to B = $x$h

B to T = $x-2$h

The problem definitely needs to be solved using the distance formula, $d=s*t$. Rearranging it for time, we get $t=d/s$

What do I do from here? I know from solving similar previous problems that I have to factor it and get the x-intercepts (one of them will be the jet's speed) but how to I solve up to that point when there are two unknowns?

I would appreciate if you provide the full solution.

Thank you!

Comment: It might help to give time and speed separate variables; perhaps $x$ for speed and $y$ for time.

Comment: if speed decreases then times increases, so time for B to T should be x+2.  if t is time for T to B and S is the speed then $t=\frac{4800}{S}$ and for B to T trip $t+2=\frac{4800}{S-2}$, substitute for t and you will get a quadratic equation

Comment: Please let me know if my answer made sense; since you've accepted it, I imagine this is the case, but don't hesitate asking any questions if a part of it didn't make sense.

Comment: @crash Thank you, I got it.

Comment: Simon, why did you ask the same question twice? We have a strict rule against duplicates, so I will delete one copy. I'm keeping this, because you accepted an answer here. But don't do this again. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R_1T_1 = 4800$

$R_2T_2 = 4800$

$R_1T_1 = (R_1-200)(T_1+2)$

$R_1T_1 = R_1T_1+2R_1-200T_1-400$

$2R_1-200\left(\frac{4800}{R_1}\right)-400=0$

$2R_1^2-400R_1-960000=0\implies R_1 = -600; +800 = +800$

$R_1 = 800; T_1 = 6$

$R_2 = 600; T_2 = 8$

Comment: What do R and T represent?

Comment: @SimonFraser My goal when answering was to sort of let you "fill in the blanks." $R_1$ represents the the first rate, the rate there; $T_1$ represents the time, etc. Make sense now?

Comment: You should define your terms.  Using $R$ for speed seems a bit strange, but if you said $R_1=$speed flying from Tokyo to Bangkok, $T_1=$time flying from Tokyo to Bangkok it would be clear.  If you want OP to fill in the blanks (which I support), the blanks should be mathematical, not understanding what the variables represent.  I would have stopped after the third line for that reason.

Comment: @RossMillikan I thought it was clear enough from how everything was laid out. I just didn't want to create a very long answer with everything unnecessarily detailed. I think it's pretty clear cut here, but the comment by OP indicates otherwise. Thus, hopefully these comments will clear up any confusion.

Comment: Is this solution different from mine?

Comment: @science See Jyrki's comment on OP's question--the OP posted the same question twice, resulting in people wasting their time answering duplicated questions. I wasn't even aware of the other question until it showed up in a review queue (I think that's how I came across it). I see that our answers really are no different. No ill intent on my part--simply the OP violating MSE rules. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $t_1, v_1$ denote time and speed from T to B and $t_2, v_2$ correspond to time and speed from B to T. So we can have the following relations

> $$ v_2=v_1-200\\ t_2= t_1+2    $$

and

> $$ 4800 = t_1 v_1 = t_2 v_2 \implies t_1 v_1 = t_2 v_2 \longrightarrow (1)$$

Substituting for $t_2, v_2$ in terms of $t_1,v_1$ in $(1)$ gives

> $$ t_1 v_1= (t_1+2)(v_1-200) \implies v_1= 100 t_1 + 200 \longrightarrow (2). $$

substituting $(2)$ in the equation $t_1 v_1 = 4800 $ gives the quadratic equation in $t_1$

> $$ t^2_1+2t_1-48 =0 \implies (t_1+8)(t_1-6)=0 \implies t_1 = 6 \implies v_1 =800 \implies v_2 =600. $$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**:Let $x$ be the jet's speed from BK to TO:

$\Rightarrow\text{time from BK to TO - time from TO to BK} = 2 \Rightarrow \dfrac{4,800}{x} - \dfrac{4,800}{x+200} = 2$

Comment: So I just solve the equation $4,800/x−4,800x/+200=2$ for x? Why is 2 on the other side, if that's the time from BK to TO - TO to BK? I would expect that to be the case if they said that the total time there and back was 2 hours, but here they say that _the difference in the times of flights is 2 hours_.

Comment: the difference in times of the $2$ flights is $2$ hrs.

Comment: Yes I know, please tell me if I misunderstand something... If the difference between the flights is 2 hours, for example flight 1 is 5 hours and flight two is 5-2 hours (2 hour difference), shouldn't we find the length of flight 1 and then subtract 2 hours from it? (Given that flight 1 timing is unknown)

Comment: Can you please explain what you did in the equation you provided? e.g. why it's x+200 instead of x-200, etc.? Sorry if I sound stupid, it's late here and I'm bad at math :P